# Navbar stretch the full width of my page

Tags: html, css

So I'm using this man code http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/ 
and I want to have the menu bar stretch the full width of my page.

I'm using the nvidia theme you can find the original code by downloading the zip file on the link above.

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/6Yy4R/

The css code

```
ul.dropdown {
    font: normal 16px "Square", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.dropdown li {
    padding: 7px 0;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: normal;
}

ul.dropdown a:link,
ul.dropdown a:visited { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
ul.dropdown a:hover { color: #005CE6; text-decoration: none; }
ul.dropdown a:active { color: #fff; }


ul.dropdown ul {
    width: 170px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: none;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    -moz-opacity: .9;
    KhtmlOpacity: .9;
    opacity: .9;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #000;
    filter: none;
}

ul.dropdown ul li.hover,
ul.dropdown ul li:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

ul.dropdown ul a:link,
ul.dropdown ul a:visited { color: #fff; }
ul.dropdown ul a:hover { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
ul.dropdown ul a:active { color: #fff; }

ul.dropdown *.dir {
    padding-right: 12px;
    background-image: none;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul.dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 14px;
}


/* -- Base style override -- */

ul.dropdown li {
 padding: 0;
}


/* -- Base style reinitiate: post-override activities -- */

ul.dropdown li.dir {
 padding: 7px 20px 7px 14px;
}

ul.dropdown ul li.dir {
 padding-right: 15px;
}


/* -- Custom -- */

ul.dropdown ul a {
 padding: 4px 5px 4px 14px;
 width: 151px; /* Especially for IE */
}

ul.dropdown ul a:hover {
background-color: #005CE6;
}


/* -- Drop-down open -- */

ul.dropdown li:hover > a.dir {
background-color: #2e2e2e;
color: #005CE6;
}

ul.dropdown ul li:hover > a.dir {
background-color: #76b900;
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your `HTML` in a fiddle

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: you can check the fiddle, the fiddle make it clear. I want to make the nav bar cover the width of my page

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a case of having the `ul` be full width you need to clear the floats and apply a bg color

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/6Yy4R/3/)

```
ul.dropdown {
    background-color: #f00;
    overflow:hidden; /* quick clearfix */
}
```

Comment: Forget to mention, I'm using this code http://jsfiddle.net/jArKR/ to make the nav bar centered. Because of the overflow: hidden i cant see the dropdown menu from my nav bar and without the overflow tag the bgcolor doesnt work